# Istio 0.8. Trace istio objects and rules applied in a request

Tags: istio

Is there any way in v0.8 to trace the istio objects that apply in a request.

Why the request has follow a specific path. For example it goes through the ingress -> gateway -> virtual service -> destination rule -> pod -> repeat...

And the applied rules in each object.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

There is a new project called Kiali that is built to achieve the goal of leveraging observability for service meshes. Kiali is based on Istio (they are working really close to istio community) and using always its latest version.

Kiali has a service graph where users can see which istio objects are applied to each service. Also, for each service, you can see more details of those istio objects.

I'll put here two screenshots as sneak peak:

Here the service list, where you can see that v3 and v2 nodes has a Circuit breaker (lightning symbol) and reviews service has a Virtual Service for routing request between v1 and v2. Note that the graph also shows health of all its services and connection between them.
[image: service graph example]

From service graph, you can navigate to each service detail page where you can find, among other things, the definitions of its attached istio objects.
[image: service details example]

For more information about Kiali, check its webpage: [kiali.io](http://kiali.io) and its github: [kiali/kiali](http://github.com/kiali/kiali)

Comment: Interesting, I knew Kiali but not that it also shows the rules configured in each element. Any way that is more documentation or analysis, I'm looking more like a log where I could see for a request what rules has been applied, something like an access log plus istio log.